# C# App - creating an auto launch app

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm just wondering if it is possible to create an app (C#) that gives the option to auto-launch?

Cheers

Comment: Auto launch? Do you mean run at startup? Or that it re-launches when it crashes?

Comment: go for registration or make windows service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you mean you would like your application to start everytime the system is booted you should register it in the startup folder or in the Run section of the registry.

Comment: Definitely do it the recommended way as this gives the user the choice to disable it - apps that force themselves onto the user do end up being flagged as malware, even if your intentions were good.

Comment: Found a good link to use the registry:

http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial151_Run-the-application-at-Windows-startup.html